# Google Maps marker loaded via Ajax are not showing

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My Google Map is showing correctly, also centering the map is working like a charm. But when I want to add some marker (just the marker, don't want to reload the whole map) nothing happens (there are no visible markers on the map).

My script looks like this:

```
function g_maps(){
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.2136522, 16.386172),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}

function g_maps_marker(coordinates){
        var locations = [ coordinates ];
        var marker, i;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            visible: true
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }
}
```

The (important) part of my ajax request looks like that:

```
...
      success:function(data){
        $('#pagination_content table').empty();
        data = $.parseJSON(data);

        i = 1;
        coordinates = "";
        for(var i in data.results) {
        $('#content_table').append("blablabla");
        coordinates += "['" + data.results[i].title + "', " + data.results[i].lat + ", " + data.results[i].lat + ", " + i++ + "], ";
        };

        coordinates = coordinates.slice(0, -2)
        g_maps_marker(coordinates);
      },
...
```

The output of `coordinates` is this:

```
['abc', 48.1857442, 48.1857442, 0], ['xyz', 48.2136522, 48.2136522, 1]
```

The function `g_maps` is called at the `document.ready()` event.

I'm using the API v3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are slicing `coordinates = coordinates.slice(0, -2);` and then again making an array out of coordinates like this `var locations = [ coordinates ];`.

I' am confused a bit. `slice` already gives you an array so why making an array again? Are you sure that your loop gets executed?

Maybe you should remove `var locations = [ coordinates ];` from `g_maps_marker` and then try again. I hope it will work.

** Edit **

After analyzing code a bit further I found that you are trying to use string which looks like an array and then trying to loop around it. This will not work.

For example

```
    a = "[1, 2, 3]";

    b = [a];

    b[0][0]; // => will result in [ and not in your desired element
```

You should use following code in-order to make array objects for coordinates.

```
    i = 1;

    coordinates = [];

    for(var i in data.results)
    {
        $('#content_table').append("blablabla");

        var coordinate = [];

        coordinate.push(data.results[i].title);

        coordinate.push(data.results[i].lat);

        coordinate.push(data.results[i].lon);

        coordinates.push(coordinate);
    };
```

Also it seems that you forgot to use `longitude` while creating coordinates array and used `latitude` two times. I have fixed this in my code.

Comment: i slice my coordinates output because i want to get rid of the last to characters -> ", "

Comment: Yeah fine. But `slice` always returns an array so there is no need of `var locations = [ coordinates ];`. It will make an array within another array which doesn't make sense, right? :-)

Comment: ok i changed the line to `var locations = coordinates;` but nothing has changed :/

Comment: Hmmmmm. Please! share what you get in `coordinates` array in `g_maps_marker` function.

Comment: exactly this output `['Item1', 48.1857442, 48.1857442, 0], ['Item2', 48.2136522, 48.2136522, 1]`

Comment: I think you are doing one thing wrong. You are making a String and then slicing it and using `[string]` to make it behave like array. Instead of doing this `coordinates += "['" + data.results[i].title + "', " + data.results[i].lat + ", " + data.results[i].lat + ", " + i++ + "], ";` and then using `coordinates = coordinates.slice(0, -2)` to remove `,` you should use make proper Array object at first place.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31205/discussion-between-imran-latif-and-john-brunner)

Comment: I looked at your code and it seems that you making a String instead of Array. Please! type the output of this command. `console.log(typeof coordinates)` by appending this line after `slice` method.

Comment: Please! try this code.


`i = 1;
        coordinates = [];
        for(var i in data.results) {
        $('#content_table').append("blablabla");
        var coordinate = array[];
        coordinate.push(data.results[i].title);
        coordinate.push(data.results[i].lat);
        coordinate.push(data.results[i].lat);
        coordinates.push(coordinate);
        };`

Comment: thanks. your solution with the new array building and changing my mistake by using "lat" and "lon" instead of "lat" for two times works great!